# Access SQL - count unique value

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, unique

SQL Columns:

```
Fishingcourse       Supervisor      Lake
AAAA                 Martha         1
BBBB                 Josh           2
CCCC                 Evelyn         1
AAAA                 Josh           1
AAAA                 Paul           2
```

How can I find `fishingcourses` that has been held at at least 2 lakes? Not including duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to compare the minimum and maximum values:

```
select fishingcourse
from t
group by fishingcourse
having min(lake) <> max(lake);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. However I tried combining two tables and couldn't get things to work. SQL code: select fishingcourse, name, price from T, F group by fishingcourse, name, price having min(lake) <> max(lake) ---> shows courses that has been held at 2 or more lakes, where to change to 3 or more lakes?